# How to make form option by image in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem is, I'm not quite sure whether I should use ordinary state or nested state.

What I want to achieve is make a form, based on clicking the image options to determine the next step of the form.

**ui router state:**

```
.state('search', {
        url: '/search/:building',
        template: '<search></search>',
        authenticate: true
      })

  .state('search.room', {
    url: '/search_room/:room' ,
    template : '<search_room></search_room>',
    authenticate : true
  })
```

**the link before the state `search:/building` should be look like this :**

`-uisref="search ({building : 'home'})"`
`-uisref="search ({building : 'office'})"`

after choose which building, it should have the menu to which room.
but I noticed that $stateparams only work in one state, the first state `search/:building`
I want to achieve this url if it is possible `/search/home/dining_room` .
I want to store the path of the user step into database eventually.

thank you so much :)

Comment: those ui-sref objects are incorrect ... other than that it's not really clear what problem is